# Does google hangout chat bots support date & time picker?

Tags: google-hangouts, botkit, botkit-middleware

I would need a date/time picker in order for user to choose date or time in google hangout chat bots.I could not found any documentation on this function in google hangout api.

Example:

staff wants to apply a leave for few days. She/he can do it by just selecting date or time in calendar.

Comment: There is a datepicker for [Gmail Addons cards](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-picker), while the options for Google Chat API are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards).

Comment: I dont see Goolge Chat api enable datepicker beside the onClick.openLink which it will call external web page.  Can u help explain which part of formatting enable datepicker?

Comment: What I meant is that currecntly there is only a datepicker for Gmail Add-ons, unfortunately so far there is none for Google Chat API.

Comment: ok got it thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently supported, no.
https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/cards#datetimepicker

> The widget that lets users to specify a date and time. Not supported
> by Google Chat apps.